# Passing constants to predefined blocks with CruiseControl.NET preprocessor

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net

What is the preferred way of "passing" preprocessor constants to predefined blocks in CC.NET?

Assuming I have the following declarations:

```
<cb:define name="ProjectHeaderBlock">
    <name>$(ProjectName)</name>
    <workingDirectory>C:\MyProjects\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
</cb:define>

<cb:define name="ProjectBlock">
    <project>
        <cb:ProjectHeaderBlock />

        <triggers />
        <tasks />
        <publishers />
    </project>
</cb:define>
```

I can pass the *ProjectName* constant in two ways:

1. Using cb:scope

   ```
   <cb:scope ProjectName="FooProject" >
       <cb:ProjectBlock />
   </cb:scope>
   ```
2. Passing directly in declaration

   ```
   <cb:ProjectBlock ProjectName="FooProject" />
   ```

They both worked properly and inner *ProjectHeaderBlock* was initialized with proper *ProjectName* value.

Are there any differences between these two options? Which one is better/more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right: They work both. The only functional difference that I'm aware of is that preprocessor contants defined in `scope` elements are overwritable i.e., they may be redefined later.

I use `scope` defined preprocessor constants for setting default values which I overwrite if necessary.

Personally I prefer the second version as it avoids nesting in your xml.